# The refresh icon of Telerik Grid can't rotate when clicking it to refresh grid

Tags: rotation, telerik, refresh

Use Telerik Grid control in my MVC project. When I try to click the refresh icon which at the left bottom of the grid to refresh the grid, I suppose the icon is rotating while the data is refreshing. But the icon isn't. Maybe the problem comes from the telerik.grid.min.js file. But I didn't find any useful solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ajax Binding or Server Binding for your Grid ?
I think the icon doesn't do anything with Server Binding because as far as I know, this simply reload the page instead of refreshing the content of the Grid.
If you are using Ajax Binding, can you check if you have any kind of JS error in your browser's console ?